# Simple, efficient way to writing to a specific line number in python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file and I need to write some contents on a specific line. I know which lines and I want to override the contents of that line.

For example, I have a 100 line text file and I want to write specifically to line 70. I know I can read line by line and keep a counter, and when I get to line 70, I can write the line that I need. I also could read the whole contents of the file, split it to a list, override the position I need and write back.

I am looking for something simpler though, something like:

```
somelibrary.writeline(file, 70, "Blah blah")
```

Is there anything like this in Python?

Comment: you can probably lad the file into memory, update it as you wish, and then overwrite the entire file back onto the original. _Not very scalable though._

Comment: There may be a library out there that provides some convenience methods for something like this, but you can't really make it more efficient than reading through the file and counting line breaks.  Lines have arbitrary lengths, so you can't just seek some fixed offset from the start of the file, and there's no metadata indexing lines or giving you information about line lengths, so ultimately, you just have to iterate over every character taking note of the ones that interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the new line is *exactly* as long as the old line, you best option would be to rewrite the file, anyway.

The easiest way to do so is to use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

```
import sys, fileinput

for count, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True)):
    if count == 69:  # Python counts from 0
        line = newvalue
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This creates a backup of the file, and output goes to a *new* file replacing the old. Writing to `sys.stdout` writes to than new file (the alternative is to use `print` but `line` still includes the newline).

Answer (score 0):

In the special case where your lines are always the same length you can use

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(FIXED_LINE_LENGTH * line_number)
    f.write(new_line)
```